# How many rows an iOS table view should contain when I use pagination?

Tags: ios, swift, pagination

I have to load some news inside a table view.

I know I have to use some pagination or lazy loading, because there may be thousands of news at some point.

My question is:

If I have for instance 10000 news, should I return that number inside:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return totalNumberOfNews
    }
```

?

Or, maybe I should return a smaller number, let's say 200-300, and whenever the user scrolls up and down to simply reset the OffSet of the table view

I know the cells are reused, and we never keep 10000 cells in memory. I am just wondering if I return 10000 or 1 million in that method would affect the performance in some way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You use the count of the news articles you've already downloaded. As the user scrolls down, at some point you request more, add them to the existing news articles, and reload the table view so it sees the new count.

Comment: Thanks Jon! So, if there are are 1000000 news, and the user scrolls down to the end, I will keep all those news in memory, right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, though that really depends on how much memory each entry takes. Realistically you'd probably want to limit it to a certain maximum. I've seen solutions that use a proxy object as the data source to  dynamically load new content, but I haven't seen one that can dynamically keep only a certain number of items around.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LazyLoading then load first 100 news and when user scrolls at bottom then load another 100.

For that Take one MutableArray and store first 100 News store that in mutable array. Now in **numberOfRowsInSection** return that mutable array count.

When user scroll to bottom then load another 100 news and append that data to **Mutable Array** and just reload the Table.

Hope this works for you.